# Python: create a compressed tar file for streamed writing

Tags: python, file-io, gzip, tar

I need to produce the tar.gzipped text file. Is there a way to create a file for constant writing (to be able to do something like `compressedFile.write("some text")`), or do I need to create a raw text file first, and compress it aftewards?

This will be quite unfortunate, as the file should be really long and well compressable.

Comment: Do you mean a gzipped file rather than a tar file?

Comment: I meant `somefile.tar.gz` inside which should be only one file with the name `somefile`

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need to tar it since there's just one file. gzip would be enough.

Comment: This wasn't me who designed the input format for the program to which i should feed this generated file, so I do need tar :)

Comment: For the people who don't need to tar the gzip stream, just use the gzip module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html#module-gzip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of how to write a compressed tarfile from a Python script:

```
import StringIO
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open('example.tar.gz', 'w:gz')

# create a file record
data = StringIO.StringIO('this is some text')
info = tar.tarinfo()
info.name = 'foo.txt'
info.uname = 'pat'
info.gname = 'users'
info.size = data.len

# add the file to the tar and close it
tar.addfile(info, data)
tar.close()
```

Result:

```
% tar tvf example.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  0 pat    users       17 Dec 31  1969 foo.txt
```

Comment: worked OK after some modifications. First: `tar.tarinfo()` didn't work, only `tar.TarInfo()` (may be wery old version of python).
Second is tricker: you need to do `data.seek(0)` before `addfile` if you modify it. Was a real challenge to find this.
Thanks!